# change ipaddr in luci

Tags: lua, luci

I want to change my ipaddr to use uci command.
Here is my code.

```
v = "111.111.111.11"

local ipaddr = io.popen("uci set network.lan.ipaddr='%s'", v)
ipaddr:close()
```

I know the code must have an error.
However, I want to change the ip address to v value.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
io.popen(string.format("uci set network.lan.ipaddr='%s'", v))
```